# Integrate Authentication For Front End And Backend Generate Using Jhipster

Tags: java, angularjs, authentication, jhipster

I'm configuring the backend (in Java) and frontend (in AngularJS) with JHipster.

I would like to use my own front end code which is in AngularJS instead of the code generated by JHipster.

The problem is:

I get an authentication error after any API call of the back end.
Is there a way to either disable authentication check in back end or do I have to add whole authentication process in front end?

Comment: Do application not need authentication?

Comment: Thanks...i do need to check authentication ...but want to know

Comment: Though you want to use your own code, it is a good choice to reuse some very useful clientside javascript file from the jhipster generated files, such as `Auth service, Principle service, and many more`. I would use nearly all files :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, my answer assume that you want to disable the authentication check for your `rest`.

To do so, browse to `SecurityConfiguration.java`

and change `HttpSecurity` configuration.

Change

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
```

To

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
```

**Note:** It is a must to use the security for any `REST` backed server.